# Creating a pdf from folder with .jpg and .png using img2pdf and sort by newest on first page

Tags: pdf, png, jpeg

I want to create a pdf. The newest picture from the folder should be on the first page and oldest last page.
I opened the terminal from the folder and used:

$ img2pdf *.jpg *.png --output combined.pdf

and it works great, but the oldest picture is on top. I just want to change the order of the images, the rest is perfect. They all have different names. And it's too many to rename all the pictures.
ChatGPT was not helpful.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `img2pdf` processes the images in the order in which the positional arguments are expanded on the command line, I'd suggests switching to the z shell, whose [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) allow you to `o`rder the results by `m`odification time:

```
$ zsh
% img2pdf *.(jpg|png)(.om) --output combined.pdf
```

Comment: Omg you are a genius. Works very well thank you. Exactly what I wanted.